# How to change the color of the woocommerce search field placeholder

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I would like to change the color of the woocommerce search field placeholder, any code to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
.search-content {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

If it does not work. Please add your code attempt.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the code doesn't work, I think that the class is differ than .search-content

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution

```css
input[type='search']::placeholder {
    color: #68aba8; }
```